# how to upload pdf or word file to media library with code

Tags: uploads, media-library

I'm adding a new feature to the cart page, that needs to upload files (word or pdf) to the media library.
I am using this code

```php
ob_start(); ?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="ArticleUpload<?php echo $values['product_id'];?>-<?php echo $quant;?>" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf">
    <input type="submit" value="atualizar">
</form> <?php 
echo ob_get_clean();

$name1 = 'ArticleUpload'.$values['product_id'].'-'.$quant;
if(isset($_FILES[$name1])){
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($name1, 0);
}
```

Once that can have 1 or 20 files to upload this is inside a while that creates let's say the 5 forms to upload file.
All works well since the second to the last one, however the first one (the upload form) sends an empty array, and so doesnt upload the file, but only the first one.
[image]
This is what it sends if it is the second upload button or higher on the php $_FILES

```php
Array
(
    [ArticleUpload856-2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 156-4errata_tabela.pdf
            [full_path] => 156-4errata_tabela.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpB7aD0k
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 49773
        )

)
```

however on the first button sends an emtpy array like so

```
Array
(
)
```

Why the first doesnt send the correct information to the php $_FILES like the rest